# How to transfer our data from using label to list box?

Tags: vb.net

I have a work before and I made the answer in labels. For example the number from text box move to label box after we click add.

eg.

```
Dim sQuoteNumber As String
    sQuoteNumber = txtQuoteNumber.Text
    lblQuoteOutputAnswer.Text = sQuoteNumber
```

This time I have to move the answer into List Box. How can I do it ? Do I just change `lblQuoteOutputAnswer.Text` to list box ?

Comment: Google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=vb.net+add+to+listbox&aq=f&oq=vb.net+add+to+listbox&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.3085j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the text to the collection:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(sQuoteNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add text to a ListBox like so:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Text = MyText;
item.Value = MyValue;
MyListBox.Items.Add(item);
```